# Assert and error-checking in C

Tags: c, error-handling, assert

I posted my code on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/130093/more-error-checking) and got the answer that I didn't have error-checking. AFAIK I can do error-checking in several ways:

- Assertions for preconditions and postconditions
- `perror` usage or similar, which I sometimes do, but I didn't learn it yet
- Manual handcoded error-checking using boolean return values from functions or similar, indicating that a call succeeded or failed

Are there more ways to do it or some specific way that is recommended? Is it better or worse to use both `perror` and assertions? The code is in [my github](https://github.com/montao/openshell) and the `main` loop looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bool donotrun = false;
    struct sigaction new_action, old_action;
    hashtable_t *hashtable = ht_create(65536);
    /* Set up the structure to specify the new action. */
    new_action.sa_handler = termination_handler;
    sigemptyset(&new_action.sa_mask);
    new_action.sa_flags = 0;

    sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, &old_action);
    if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
        sigaction(SIGINT, &new_action, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGHUP, NULL, &old_action);
    if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
        sigaction(SIGHUP, &new_action, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, &old_action);
    if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
        sigaction(SIGTERM, &new_action, NULL);


    void *pParser;
    char *c;


    int index = 0;
    int i;
    char *cvalue = NULL;
    const char *commandFile = "";
    bool quietFlag;

    while (1) {
        index = 0;
        i = getopt_long(argc, argv, "pc:vh",
                        options, &index);
        if (i == -1)
            break;
        switch (i) {
            case 'p': {
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            case 'v': {
                printf("sh OpenShell version 0.1(a)\n");
                printf("Version: %s\n", VERSION);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            }
            case 'h': {
                usage();
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            }
            case 'c': {
                cvalue = optarg;
                command(cvalue, hashtable);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }

            case 'f':
                /*
                 * Execute commands from file.
                 * This is used for osh script files.
                 * The quiet flag is also set.
                 */
                if ((argc != 1) || commandFile)
                    usage();

                quietFlag = true;
                argc--;

                break;


            case '?':
                if (optopt == 'c')
                    fprintf(stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
                else if (isprint (optopt))
                    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
                else
                    fprintf(stderr,
                            "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                            optopt);
            default: {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    getPath();
    pParser = (void *) ParseAlloc(malloc);
    char *copy = "";

    for (; ;) {
        bool scanning = true;
        bool calc = true;
        while (scanning) {
            char *line = NULL;
            line = readline("$ ");
            if (line == NULL) {
                /* No more lines, so exit the loop. */
                break;
            }
            if (line)
                copy = strdup(line);

            if (line && !strstr(line, "for") && !strstr(line, "==") && !strstr(line, "if") && strstr(line, "=")) {
                donotrun = true;
                char str[128];
                char *ptr;
                strcpy(str, line);
                strtok_r (str, "=", &ptr);
                ht_set(hashtable, str, ptr);
            }

            if (!scanning)
                break;

            if (!isatty(fileno(stdin))) {
                *argv++;
                readFile(*argv++, hashtable);
                free(line);
                exit(0);
            }
            else {

                if (!donotrun) {
                    line = str_replace(line, " | ", "|");
                    line = str_replace(line, " |", "|");

                    command(line, hashtable);
                }
                donotrun = false;
                add_history(copy);

            }
            free(copy);
        }
    }
    //  ParseFree(pParser, free);FIXME: where should this go?
    return 0;
}
```

Then I had assertions that I had to comment out during development and now I'm not sure what the assertions should be.

```
/* Returns a struct that has the number of "chunks" the list of chunks.
 * Splits the command by char | and then by whitespace and return a list of struct pointers
 */
struct str_list *list_split(const char *a_str, char *a_delim) {

    char **result = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    char *tmp = (char *) a_str;
    char *ctmp;
    char *token = "";
    char *last_comma = 0;
    char *tmp2 = (char *) a_str; /* TODO: This variable can reuse tmp */
    //char *delim[2];
    //delim[0] = a_delim;
    struct str_list *chunks = NULL;
    /* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
    while (*tmp) {
        if (*a_delim == *tmp) {
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }
    /* Add space for trailing token. */
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);
    count++;
    result = alloc_argv(count);
    char **tmpresult = alloc_argv(count);
    chunks = malloc(count * sizeof *chunks);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
        return chunks;;
    }
    if (result) {
        size_t idx = 0;
        token = strtok((char *) strdup(a_str), "|");
        int a = 0;
        while (token) {
//            assert(idx < count); Why must I turn off assertions?
            tmpresult[a] = strdup(token);
            a++;
            ctmp = strdup(token);
            *(result + idx++) = ctmp; /* memory leak! how to free() */;
            token = strtok(0, a_delim);
        }
//        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }
    chunks->argv = alloc_argv(BUFFER_SIZE);//malloc(chunks->size * sizeof(char *) * 1);
    int i = 0;
    chunks = tokenize(&i, chunks, result, count, tmp2);
    chunks->pipes = i; /* important! to get this right */
    free(ctmp);
    return expand_shell(tmpresult, chunks);
}
```

Comment: Wait, are you asking about checking for errors from things you *use*, or are you asking about implementing such error emission and checking for things you *develop yourself*?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm wondering why I had to comment out my assertions and I'm wondering where I should use assertions in code that I write. In some places I already use `perror` but I don't know the details.

Comment: `perror()` does not check for errors. It just logs the long-text error message for the current value of `errno` to `stderr`.

Comment: You use assertions when "something very wrong has happened, no point continuing"

Comment: @user3528438 That's actually what I'm wondering. "Where should I use assertions?" I had assertions, refactored and then I had to comment out the assertions but the code worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, assertions should be used during development and testing only. assert is actually a macro. When you build in debug configuration, it performs the check and exit if false. When you are in release configuration, it does nothing. assert should therefore be used to check for programming errors.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/

What you cannot do with assert is to check for runtime errors, meaning errors that happen during program execution due to the environment or to user input, e.g. the program cannot open or write a file, the user enters a string when a number is expected, a network connection cannot be established, etc. You want these checks to happen both in debug and release modes.

I think that the two other error checking methods that you mention, perror and checking return values, always go together. One normally checks the return value of a function, then prints a message (with perror or other function), and then do error recovery or exit. perror itself just prints a message and the program continues unless you do something else.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/

Normally one should check the return value of external function calls, and also check all inputs to the program for correctness. Most library functions can fail, including malloc or printf, but depending on your level of paranoia it's enough to check only the ones most likely to cause trouble (files, network, library or device initialization, etc), depending on your application.